# Running multiple threads in parallel using Webworker-Threads for Node.js

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

I am VERY new to using Node.js and WebWorker-Threads for Node.js (https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads). The WebWorker-Threads module is based on Thread-A-Gogo (https://github.com/xk/node-threads-a-gogo).

Here is a summary of my problem:

- I have a file called "readFile.js", which contains code to read a csv
  file that is passed in, and converts the csv data into a 2D array.
- I want the function ""exports.parseCSV" within "readFile.js" to be
  loaded and executed in multiple worker threads, with each thread
  running in parallel.
- I have a file, "test1.js", which attempts to do point 2 by using a
  thread pool:

```
var Threads = require('webworker-threads');
var parser = require('./readFile.js');

var numThreads = 3;
var threadPool = Threads.createPool(numThreads);
threadPool.all.eval(parser.parseCSV);

for (var i = 1; i <=3; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        threadPool.any.eval(parser.parseCSV("csvFile.csv"), function (err, val) {
            if (i == 3) {
                console.log("bye!");
                threadPool.destroy();
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

- I have another file, "test2.js", which attempts to do point 2 by
  manually creating threads:

```
function cb (err, result) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log("\n" + " ERROR! ERROR! ERROR!");
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(" NO ERROR!");
    thread.destroy();
}

var Threads = require('webworker-threads');
var parser = require('./readFile.js');
var thread = Threads.create();

thread.eval(parser.parseCSV);
thread.eval(parser.parseCSV("csvFile.csv"), cb); 
thread.eval(parser.parseCSV);
thread.eval(parser.parseCSV("csvFile.csv"), cb);
thread.eval(parser.parseCSV);
thread.eval(parser.parseCSV("csvFile.csv"), cb);
```

- When I run a "test[x].js" file using the command `node test[x].js` in the command prompt, the threads seem to be working but it appears as if they are being executed sequentially, and not in parallel. I say this based on the outputs of the time each thread starts, which I print out to command prompt window.

How do I execute multiple Webworker-Threads which run in parallel in the background? I want the threads to start at the same time and end at the same (if that is possible). I have looked at the API for the WebWorker-Threads but I haven't been able to solve this problem. Once this works, I would like to use the same methodology to not only read the csv files, but also store their contents into a database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have more than one process executing what your threads should do? Does your program need to access the content of all the threads parsed on the same process?